# Put Integer ArrayList into a a single String

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Trying to put an ArrayList of Integers into a single string so I can create a popup window w/ the string of the values. Here is my attempt at it:

```
} else if (control == show) {


            for(Integer s : array) {

                s1 += " " + s;
            }



        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your values are: " + s1);
    }
```

And well... this code doesn't throw it into a single String. New to Arrays and ArrayLists. This is part of a learning excise.

Comment: Please define *doesn't work* :)

Comment: Question is very vague. Please elaborate with sufficient examples and description.

Comment: @TheLostMind what I mean by that is, It doesn't string together the ints inside the ArrayList into a String. New to ArrayLists, and this is part of a learning exercise.  Thanks!

Comment: _It doesn't string together the ints inside the ArrayList._ So what does it do?

Comment: You should be editing your question and adding all these details there.

Comment: Have you defined `s1`?  Have you tried using `StringJoiner` (available in Java 8)?

Comment: use toString() method of List - array.toString()

Comment: @Arjit - Actually using `toString()` will give *comma* seperated values :)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have defined s1 as a String and not yet looked at Java 8, for I am brand new to java and would like to stick to what I know (or kinda know), but thanks for the help anyways

Comment: . @Arjit Thank you for the .toString() method reminder, I completely forgot about that, and It works for this purpose, but maybe not in the near future for more complex programs, but thank you anyways.  If anyone has any other ideas of how you can put the Array into the String please post here. I might need them in the future, thanks everyone!

Comment: ok. but the existing code works fine. Whats the problem @CooperScott

Comment: @CooperScott, can use Arrays.toString(array); for arrays also

Comment: You're trying to add the Integer boxed type to a string with + which is basically the same as s1 += "" + Object in which case you would need to call .toString() on the Object. Instead, try doing this: s1 += "" + s.toString().

Comment: @JamesS That worked perfect thanks! except the popup says: Your values are: null <number> <numberr> <number>

There is a null in there. Hm...

Comment: @CooperScott - to remove null - declare String st = "";

Comment: @Arjit Perfect! problem solved completely. Don't understand why having to declare it before defining it elseware effected it, but I guess I will learn that once I get a better understanding of Java. Thanks guys!

Comment: make sure your `array` is an `integer` `array` and the string `s1` is declared and initialised. `String s1 = ""`

Comment: @CooperScott To understand why it's null see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html . The default String(or any object) value is null and the statement s1 += " " + s is equivalent to s1 = s1 + " " + s, so if s1 is initially defaulted to null you'll see a null value at the beginning of the string when it's printed.

Comment: @CooperScott - its because you are directly appending (s1 += " " + s;) to the string in your for loop. by default strings will be null if not initialized, so its appending null in your first run of loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

initialize your `string s1`.

```
String s1 = "";

for(Integer s : array)
{
    s1 += s;
}  

JOptionpane.showMessageDialog(null, s1);
```